# Where is the default JavaScript plugin for intelliJ?

Tags: javascript, plugins, intellij-idea

So I don't have the ostensibly default JavaScript plugin for intelliJ-

"Prerequisites

Before you start working with JavaScript, make sure that JavaScript Support plugin is enabled. The plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and activated by default. If it is not, enable the plugin as described in the section Enabling and Disabling Plugins."

I can't seem to find where this plugin is available on the internet, it doesn't show up in my intelliJ plugins list. Is it "Bindows"? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript plugin is one of the plugins installed by default, so you do not need to install it by yourself. The plugin could be turned on/off in File > Settings > Plugins

However it is included in Ultimate Edition (the paid one) only.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the ultimate one. Thanks!